# get value from block JSON

Tags: python, json, python-requests

im trying to get value 30 from the first 'age' using python

```
import json

# some JSON:
x = '{"data":[{"name":"John", "age":30, "city":"New York"}, {"name":"Wati", "age":15, "city":"konoha"}]}'

# parse x:
y = json.loads(x)

# the result is a Python dictionary:
print(y["data"]["age"][0])
```

but i got

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

im trying to get value 30 from the first 'age'

Comment: you are accessing wrong path for the key. it should be `print(y["data"][0]["age"])`

Answer (score 1):

You just mixed up the order of the indexing

```py
y['data'][0]['age']
```

```
30
```